# Badly distributed sequences in $[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-distribution

Let $d(X)$ be the asymptotic density of a set $X$ of positive integers, i.e.,
$$
d(X):=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|X\cap [1,n]|}{n},
$$
whenever this limit exists.

Fix also a sequence $(x_n)$ of reals taking values in the closed interval $[0,1]$.

> **Question**. Is it possible that, for each real $x$, there exists an open neighborhood $I$ of $x$ such that 
>   $
> d(\{n: x_n \in I\})=0?
> $

Comment: How is the measure $|~\cdot~|$ defined?

Comment: $|X|$ is the cardinality of $X$

Comment: So are you asking for some $x_n$ (which we might choose as we please) such that for any $x$ the density is $0$? (Also reminder to self: upvote when quota is replenished).

Comment: Exactly, I am asking about the existence of a real sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying the property in the question for each $x \in \mathbf{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Since $[0,1]$ is compact, we find a finite set of neighborhoods $U_1, \ldots, U_m$ covering $[0,1]$.

Assume that $d(\{n:x_n \in U_k\})$ exists and equals zero for every $k$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ we have an $n$ such that for every $k$ we have
$$
\frac{|\{i\leq n: x_i \in U_k|}{n} < \epsilon.
$$

It follows
$$ 1 \leq \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{|\{i\leq n: x_i \in U_k|}{n} < m\epsilon $$

where the first inequality is due to the $U_k$ covering $[0,1]$.

by picking $\epsilon$ small enough, in particular less than $\tfrac{1}{m}$ we have a contradiction.